# РазработкаUSB OTG Arduino и Android

Tags: android, usb, arduino

Ситуация в двух словах: Arduino - собирает данные с сенсоров и передает на Android. Android их принимает и если нужно выдает команду на Arduino, которая исполняет их (например дает сигнал запуска генератора) и т.д.
Зоопарк и суть вопроса:

1. Есть Arduino DUE, с APK на борту, подключен программным портом USB к ноуту. Тут собственно правлю код в Arduino IDE.
2. Есть планшетка Asus, которая подключена к нативному порту Arduino Due по OTG кабелю. Принимает и передает данные в Android.Connect присутствует.
3. Разработку для Android веду в Android Studio.

Собственно как мне вести и разработку и отладку программы на самом Android девайсе, не переключая провода?

Comment: Решение вполне очевидно - подключать Arduino через Bluetooth.

Comment: да, я в курсе такого решения. Но не оно не применимо в моем случае.

Answer (score 1):

Очевидно, что в таком случае никак. При подключении устройства к телефону, он работает в режиме USB-host. При подключении к компьютеру в режиме USB-device.

Максимум что доводилось делать - USB-OTG кабель, который заряжает телефон.

Как вариант - можете собрать из двух проводов один с тумблером (либо переходник microUSB - тумблер - 2USB). При переключении положения тумблера переключать поключенные провода.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Контроллер находится в экранированном трюме катера. К нему подключены 16 датчиков. Due питается от внешнего питания. Android устройство по USB-OTG  кабелю заряжается. Один USB кабель или 16 проводов... Значит придется переключать при разработке.

Comment: @Stalker1204 Добавил схемку переходника, который имел в виду. За картинку извиняюсь, только paint под рукой.

Answer (score 1):

Все проще.
Установил на Android "ADB wifi no root". (бесплатно)
Подключил Android-устройство по кабелю к компьютеру и в терминале Android Studio выполнил команды (собственно они написаны при запуске ADB wifi):

1. adb tctip 5555
2. adb connect IP_ADDRESS -  сетевой адрес устройства андроида.
3. Отключил кабель. Все работает.

У меня на Mac os "adb" находилось по этому пути: /Users/%USER_NAME%/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools

Answer (score 0):

Дотяните RS232 от ардуины из трюма до места, где установлен планшет. Если расстояние слишком велико (больше 10 метров для скорости 9600), используйте RS485.

После этого, поставьте конвертер RS232 - bluetooth (на базе HC05) и подключайте девайс к андроиду через bluetooth.

Итоговая схема Arduino -> RS232 (485) -> Bluetooh -> планшет.

Answer (score 0):

USB от ардуины завести в ноутбук, на ноутбуке организовать виртуальный bluetooth com-порт, который соединить с андроидом.

Два компорта в ноутбуке соединить при помощи программы socat или ее аналога.